# error: snap "android-studio" has "install-snap" change in progress

Tags: software-installation, android, snap

I was trying to install Android studio in ubuntu 20.04. I used this command `sudo snap install android-studio --classic`. But after 54% download , my pc freezes and restarts automatically. After opening my pc , again open my terminal and execute the same command. This time it shows `error: snap "android-studio" has "install-snap" change in progress` error. What I need to do? Do I need to kill the PID.

Comment: I have the same problem...

Comment: @Fadi You can check the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

try the following
`snap changes`

You should get something like this

...
123  Doing   2018-04-28T10:40:11Z  -  Install "foo" snap
...

Then do
`sudo snap abort [ID]`

This will abort the process that you want to kill. Hope I was helpful

Comment: HI I had the following result:  
`error: cannot abort change 20 with nothing pending`, while still showing `ID   Status  Spawn                Ready                Summary
20   Done    today at 15:07 SAST  today at 15:07 SAST  Remove "android-studio" snap
21   Error   today at 15:08 SAST  today at 15:13 SAST  Install "android-studio" snap from "latest/stable" channel`

Answer (score 0):

No matter what just restart PC. Then try to finish download at once in terminal , because there is no way to pause.